# Azure Lifecycle Management Scenario

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Trying to work out a sample question on Blob Lifecyle management but wanted to know if the answer is correct based on the scenario. Would be helpful to get insights if this isn't correct.

**Scenario ->**
[image]

**Answer ->**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is correct.

The settings are correct to move to cool/archive tier, and delete the blobs.

And for the cost, it's also correct to move less-use data to cool tier / rarely less-use data to archive tier which can save money.

And the auditing data in archive tier can be available in 10 days after the request is made.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking the slots:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "name": "ruleFoo",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [ "blockBlob" ],
          "prefixMatch": [ "container1/foo" ]
        },
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "tierToCool": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 30 },
            "tierToArchive": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 90 },
            "delete": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 365 }
          },
          "snapshot": {
            "delete": { "daysAfterCreationGreaterThan": 90 }
```

What you need to remember going into the exam is the order of things, eg if you're asked to Deploy a web app, then first you'll need a resource group, then a service plan, then a web app, then you can deploy. Ok, they will give you the commands for most questions (and coding knowledge won't really help except for one question). You need to know how to use Azure. It's quite easy to logically answer the questions using a process of elimination.

> Slot 1: blobBase
> Slot 2: tierToCool
> Slot 3: tierToArchive
> Slot 4: snapshot
> Slot 5: delete

Do this in the Portal and use the "Export Template" menu to generate the ARM template.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for explanation and details !